# Can MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining prevent an expensive argument from evaluating if it is not used?

Tags: c#

Say I have a function `Log`:

```
void Log(string message, LogLevel logLevel) {
    if (logLevel >= chosenLogLevel)
        Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

which I call with an expensive to evaluate argument:

```
Log(SlowFunction(), someLogLevel);
```

If I were to apply `MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining` to `Log`, would `SlowFunction` be invoked if `logLevel` was smaller than `chosenLogLevel`?

Comment: Yes, parameter value evaluation happens at the call site, before the method is invoked.  Only [Conditional] could stop that from happening, doesn't help you here since *someLogLevel* is a variable.  You need an if-statement to get ahead.  Been done, no big deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Inlining will not help here**

Your current code is this

```cs
void Log(string message, LogLevel logLevel) {
    if (logLevel >= chosenLogLevel)
        Console.WriteLine(message);
}

void Foo()
{
    Log(SlowFunction(), someLogLevel);
}
```

After inlining it becomes:

```cs
void Foo()
{
    var message = SlowFunction();
    var logLevel = someLogLevel;
    if (logLevel >= chosenLogLevel)
        Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

`logLevel` can then be further inlined, but `SlowFunction()` by definition must be called before the check.

---

**One way to avoid this is to pass `message` as `Func<string>`:**

```cs
void Log(Func<string> message, LogLevel logLevel) {
    if (logLevel >= chosenLogLevel)
        Console.WriteLine(message());
}

void Foo()
{
    Log(SlowFunction, someLogLevel);
}
```